# youtube API to get video's channel's # subscribers

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I call the YT sreachByKeyword API.

```
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    q: sh.getRange("D4").getValue(), 
    maxResults: sh.getRange("D6").getValue(),
        order:sh.getRange("D7").getValue(),
        publishedAfter:sh.getRange("D8").getValue(),
        //relatedToVideoId:"kdJvv3RipNY",
        type:sh.getRange("D10").getValue(),
        videoDuration:sh.getRange("D11").getValue(),
        location:sh.getRange("D12").getValue(),
        locationRadius:sh.getRange("D13").getValue(),
        relevanceLanguage:sh.getRange("D14").getValue()

  });
```

How can I add the following search restrictions?

Or see data about the results?

Maybe other API? Or not possible?

- The channel # subscribers.
- Negative filters
- Potential daily reach
- Channel's location (even if type==`video`)
- Video duration (min)

Answer (score 0):

I would have to use all 3 APIs

video object:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration

channel object
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

search object
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search